# How to get a MethodInfo in the ThreadContext class?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying this:

```
Type ThreadContextType = typeof(Application).GetNestedType("ThreadContext", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
MethodInfo FDoIdleMi = ThreadContextType.GetMethod("FDoIdle", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
    BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { typeof(Int32) }, null);
```

ThreadContextType is ok but FDoIdleMi is null. I know there is something wrong in the GetMethod call because FDoIdle comes from the UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent interface.

How to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fully-qualify the method name, because they're using explicit interface implementation:

```
Type type = typeof( Application ).GetNestedType( "ThreadContext",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic );
MethodInfo doIdle = type.GetMethod(
    "System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FDoIdle",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance );
```

For the record, reflecting on non-public members is generally bad practice, but you probably already know that.

**EDIT** In the spirit of teaching a person to fish, I figured this out by calling `GetMethods(...)` on the type object, and examining the returned array to see how the methods were named. Sure enough, the names included the complete namespace specification.

Comment: I did try with UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FDoIdle but forgot the System.Windows.Forms prefix. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

It's hacky, but this works:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Test 
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Type clazz = typeof(Application).GetNestedType("ThreadContext", BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        Type iface = typeof(Form).Assembly.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods+IMsoComponent");
        InterfaceMapping map = clazz.GetInterfaceMap(iface);
        MethodInfo method = map.TargetMethods.Where(m => m.Name.EndsWith(".FDoIdle")).Single();
        Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
    }
}
```

There are more surefire ways of matching the target method, but this happens to work this time :)

Comment: Maybe less obvious than what Charlie wrote, but very interesting.